# How do I connect to DB2 via ibm_db python package

Tags: python, db2, odbc, dsn

I'm trying to connect with an on-prem DB2 database via python but have been unsuccessful over the past few days.  I am hoping the community can help me decipher error messages and offer help from their experience.

My goal is to install the Python ibm_db library on my Windows 7 laptop and connect to our DB2 instance

I cannot get the ibm_db.connect() method to recognize system DSN or user DSN that are known good (I use them to connect to DB2 via Sql Server Management Studio (SSMS))

I get the below errors from various connection combinations (shown below) but I have not found any reference that says what the errors mean, and what I may be able to do to resolve the issue.  I have searched and read dozens of IBM websites and documents, but none mention this information.
 --> I have a feeling I am missing some simple step, but i don't know what i don't know at this point :)

Notes on System Configuration ::

- Windows 7 laptop
- DB2 version 7.3
- Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:17:26) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
- Python library versions installed that seem pertinent
- ibm-db (2.0.8)
- ibm-db-sa (0.3.3)
- pyodbc (4.0.16)
- pyOpenSSL (17.0.0)
- I have the iSeries Navigator installed and working, which included the iSeries ODBC driver.  It works perfectly to connect to on-prem DB2 instances
- I have the DB2 Command Line interface installed, which added a DRIVER with name IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - C_clidriver in the registry and in the 64-bit ODBC Manager driver list
- Here is a File DSN I created from the iSeries ODBC driver that works, but look quite different from the DSN I'm using for the IBM CLI driver:

  [ODBC]
  DRIVER=iSeries Access ODBC Driver
  DATABASE=DBASE
  PKG=QGPL/DEFAULT(IBM),2,0,1,0,512
  LANGUAGEID=ENU
  DFTPKGLIB=QGPL
  DBQ=QGPL
  SYSTEM=DBSYS

**First Attempt :: basic connection with a full DSN specified:**

```
>>> import ibm_db
>>> dsn = "DATABASE=dbname;HOSTNAME=hostname.domain;PORT=466;PROTOCOL=TCPIP"
>>> conn = ibm_db.connect(dsn,'mytextuid','password')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL10007N Message "0" could not be retrieved.  
  **Reason code: "6". SQLCODE=-1366**
```

**Next :: Add a driver with name with EXACT driver name as is in the registry**

```
>>> dsn = "DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - C_clidriver};HOSTNAME=hostname.domain;PORT=446;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=mytextuid;PWD=password;"
>>> conn = ibm_db.connect(dsn,'CROWLEY','July2017')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver]  
  **SQLSTATE=01S00 SQLCODE=-99999**
```

**Next  :: try a different format DSN, combining DATABASE, HOSTNAME, AND PORT**

```
>>> dsn = "DATABASE=Dbname:hostname.domain:466;PROTOCOL=TCPIP"
>>> conn = ibm_db.connect(dsn,'mytextuid','password')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL10007N Message "0" could not be retrieved.  
  **Reason code: "6". SQLCODE=-1024**
```

**Next :: try a System DSN that is Known Good because I use it in SSMS**

```
>>> conn = ibm_db.connect('DSN=SYSTEM_DB2_DSN','mytextuid','password')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL10007N Message "0" could not be retrieved.  
  **Reason code: "6". SQLCODE=-1013**
```

**Next :: try a User DSN with same configuration as above**

```
>>> conn = ibm_db.connect("DSN=USER_DB2_DSN","mytextuid","password")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver]  
  **SQLSTATE=HY009 SQLCODE=-99999**
```

**Next :: Enabled Trace on the ODBC System DSN (result: ODBC Admin Hangs on connection)**

```
C:\clidriver\db2trace.log>cat p8516t4948.cli


[ Process: 8516, Thread: 4948 ]
[ Date & Time:               02/27/2018 15:28:34.282526 ]
[ Product:                   QDB2/NT64 DB2 v11.1.2021.1452 ]
[ Level Identifier:          0203010F ]
[ CLI Driver Version:        10.01.0000 ]
[ Informational Tokens:      "DB2 v11.1.2021.1452","s1709221349","DYN1709221349W
IN64","Fixpack 2a" ]
[ Install Path:              C:\clidriver ]
[ db2cli.ini Location:       C:\Users\mytextuid\db2cli.ini ]
[ db2cli.ini Location2:      C:\ProgramData\IBM\DB2\C_clidriver\cfg\db2cli.ini ]

[ db2dsdriver.cfg Location:  C:\ProgramData\IBM\DB2\C_clidriver\cfg\db2dsdriver.
cfg ]
[ CLI Driver Type:           IBM Data Server Driver For ODBC and CLI ]



[0000008516 0000004948] [02/27/2018 15:28:34.283197] SQLAllocEnv(phEnv=&0000000000392b00 )
[0000008516 0000004948] [02/27/2018 15:28:34.284702]     ---> Time elapsed - 0 seconds

[0000008516 0000004948] [02/27/2018 15:28:34.299819] SQLAllocEnv( phEnv=0:1 )
[0000008516 0000004948] [02/27/2018 15:28:34.301458]     <--- SQL_SUCCESS   Time elapsed - +1.826100E-002 seconds

[0000008516 0000004948] [02/27/2018 15:28:34.302199] SQLAllocConnect( hEnv=0:1,phDbc=&0000000000392b08 )
[0000008516 0000004948] [02/27/2018 15:28:34.304124]     ---> Time elapsed - +7.410000E-004 seconds

[0000008516 0000004948] [02/27/2018 15:28:34.305055] SQLAllocConnect( phDbc=0:1)
[0000008516 0000004948] [02/27/2018 15:28:34.305902]     <--- SQL_SUCCESS   Time
 elapsed - +3.703000E-003 seconds

[0000008516 0000004948] [02/27/2018 15:28:34.306285] SQLDriverConnect( hDbc=0:1,hwnd=0:0,szConnStrIn="DSN=DSNNAME;UID=mytextuid;PWD=********;AUTOCOMMIT=0;CONNECTTYPE=1;", cbConnStrIn=-3, szConnStrOut=&0000000000103230, cbConnStrOutMax=256,pcbConnStrOut=&00000000001031f6,fDriverCompletion=SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT )
[0000008516 0000004948] [02/27/2018 15:28:34.308920]     ---> Time elapsed - +3.830000E-004 seconds
    sqlccconnr( timeout - +0.000000E+000, protocol - 0x03 )
```

**Next :: watching c:\ProgramData\IBM\DB2\C_clidriver\db2diag.log**

I test the connect for the DSN in ODBC Admin and this is the entry I receive... Note :: the "DB", APPID, and HOSTNAME have been obfuscated in the below... I have no idea why a license is required to use this driver, if that is even the issue

```
2018-02-27-16.29.43.560000-480 E27622F847           LEVEL: Error
PID     : 13452                TID : 4948           PROC : odbcad32.exe
INSTANCE:                      NODE : 000           DB   : DBNAME
APPID   : my.ipa.ddr.ess.65253.180228002943
HOSTNAME: ${COMPUTERNAME}
EDUID   : 4948
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, Connection Manager, sqleuPerformServerActivationCheck, probe:110
MESSAGE : ADM12008C  The product "IBM Data Server Driver For ODBC and CLI" does 
          not have a valid license key installed and the evaluation period has 
          expired. Functions specific to this product are not enabled. If you 
          have licensed this product, ensure the license key is properly 
          installed. You can install the license using the db2licm command. The 
          license file can be obtained from your licensed product CD.
```

Comment: Please edit question to add three bits of Missing information: (1) which python version (2) python bitness (3) version of ibm_db module.  Also add if you are able to connect to the DSN via the windows odbcad32 GUI.

Comment: Hi mao, thanks for your comment.  I added the python version.
Please pardon my naivety, but how do I determine (2) and (3) ?

Comment: Your symptom suggests the PATH does not contain the Db2 client driver files, so check your PATH.
In a CMD.EXE window, use `pip list` to show what modules are installed and at which version. 

The bitness of your Python should match the bitness of your Db2-client and the Db2-client directory needs to be on the PATH.

To find the bitness of your Python, in a CMD.EXE window just type `python` and read the couple of lines it displays, that includes version and bitness information. Use Ctrl-Z to quit, or exit().

Comment: Okay, I added more details for the env configuration.  I will try the path as you suggest.  One thing :: When I test the connection in ODBC Admin64, it says "SQL1598N An attempt to connect to the database server failed because of a licensing problem.  SQLSTATE=42968".  I had not tested that before, so I'm looking into that.

Comment: confused by what you write in the question "...iSeries ODBC driver. It works perfectly to connect to on-prem DB2 instances", seems to conflict with SQL1598N report. How were you testing that it works perfectly?

Comment: I hav e two different System DSN: 
1) iSeries Access ODBC Driver (v11.64.00.00 from IBM Corporation, CWBODBC.DLL); 
and 2) IBM DB2 ODBC Driver (v11.01.2021.1452 from IBM, DB2CLIO.DLL).   I have used #1 via SSMS to connect and the File DSN connects fine (added to description).  However, #2 I can't figure out how to configure so that it connects in ODBC Admin or ibm_db

Comment: I also added a full trace capture for when I am testing the DSN.  I was able to get further, as the DSN Test "hangs" on the last step indefinitely, with ODBC Admin interface Not Responding and the spinning circle of death.

Comment: It appears the two ODBC drivers for Db2 do not coexist in your configuration. I'm not sure why you need two. It seems wise to use one Db2 driver, use the one that works with all your apps including python ibm_db.   If you want to use the "IBM Db2 ODBC Driver" then either it must connect to a gatweay(that runs licensed Db2 connect), or you must add a personal Db2-connect license to your workstation to connect directly without a gateway.   Instead, if you wish to use the "i Series Access ODBC driver" , it needs to work with all your apps and python ibm_db.

Answer (score 0):

Try this(Python3 and Python2):

```
import ibm_db as db2

def make_connexion(server, port, database, username, password, timeout):
    return db2.connect('DATABASE={0};'.format(database) +
                  'HOSTNAME={0};'.format(server) +
                  'PORT={0};'.format(str(port)) +
                  'PROTOCOL=TCPIP;' +
                  'UID={0};'.format(username) +
                  'PWD={0};'.format(password) +
                  'ConnectTimeout={0};'.format(str(timeout))
                  , '', '')

# sample connexion object
connexion = make_connexion('localhost', '50000', 'database', 'username', 'password', '30')
```

Comment: I pasted as indicated and it did not work unfortunately:

Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL10007N Message "0" could not be retrieved.  Reason code: "6". SQLCODE=-1366

Comment: Can you post the version of the ODBC driver you have installed locally, and the version of your DB2?   Also, is your DB2 really running on your local machine?  or did you just put "localhost" there as a placeholder.

Lastly, I have received errors in some testing that says something like (client is trying to use TCPIP but the destination is using 'SOCKETS')... wondering if you could explain more about how the odbc connection security is implemented.  Thanks.

Comment: I ran this code inside a change root environment(a Debian 8 in SUSE ELS 11) without Db2 native client library(no remote sqlib directory) or a odbc connector installed(when you install ibm_db the odbc driver is also downloaded as a dependency); I tested this code to connect to Db2 10.1 Z/OS and Db2 10.5 LUW without any problem.

Comment: I'm not sure, But I think Db2 connection is not secure by default.

Comment: got it,  I think my configuration is different.  Per Mao's comments above, I am probably connecting to the wrong place, and getting a license error as a result.  Many thanks for your response, though.  The code is a wonderful help once I figure out the right info to put in the variables :)

Comment: I tried to connect with this code to 2 remote instances of Db2 10.1 Z/OS, one of them wanted a license file and I couldn't connect to that one(couldn't find a way to use license with odbc on that occasion I guess).

Comment: Thank you for checking this.  This at least correlates with my findings, so the license looks like the smoking gun at this point.

Comment: any ideas about having a license file? my connection is hanging with no error